# worhp interfacing issues with casadi under windows 10

Tags: worhp

I am trying to use worhp in casadi but I receive the following error message:

```
Error (License): Could not open license file.
* Local MACs:
   - 48:2a:e3:58:b0:47
   - 00:ff:76:44:3b:be
   - 94:e6:f7:51:bb:f3
   - 96:e6:f7:51:bb:f2
   - 94:e6:f7:51:bb:f2
   - 94:e6:f7:51:bb:f6
WorhpInit: Could not obtain license.
 Unsuccessful termination: License error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\envs\casadi37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-c949571b9b16>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('G:/Il mio Drive/Lavoro_GoogleDriveUnipi/Repos/MaikGitLab/master_thesis/nmpc_problem.py', wdir='G:/Il mio Drive/Lavoro_GoogleDriveUnipi/Repos/MaikGitLab/master_thesis')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "G:/Il mio Drive/Lavoro_GoogleDriveUnipi/Repos/MaikGitLab/master_thesis/nmpc_problem.py", line 488, in <module>
    mpc_instance.solve()
  File "G:/Il mio Drive/Lavoro_GoogleDriveUnipi/Repos/MaikGitLab/master_thesis/nmpc_problem.py", line 331, in solve
    lbg=self.g_lower_bound, ubg=self.g_upper_bound)
  File "C:\casadiPackages\casadi-windows-py37-v3.5.1-64bit\casadi\casadi.py", line 13343, in __call__
    return self.call(kwargs)
  File "C:\casadiPackages\casadi-windows-py37-v3.5.1-64bit\casadi\casadi.py", line 12214, in call
    return _casadi.Function_call(self, *args)
RuntimeError: .../casadi/interfaces/worhp/worhp_interface.cpp:307: Main: Initialisation failed. Status: LicenseError
```

The code should be right since it runs smoothly on a Linux installation of a collaborator of mine.

I am using casadi 3.5.1 (just downloaded) under win10.
I obtained the license file for worhp (I am using version worhp_1.13-2_win64) for the MAC address which is returned by the getmac.exe (the application distributed with worhp to select the correct MAC address which turns out to be the first address returned 48:2a:e3:58:b0:47). The file is located in C:\WORHP/worhp.lic.
I also redundantly added the same worhp.lic in the bin subfolder of the worhp folders located in my local directories and also in the folder where my main.py is sitting.
It seems I have the environment variables set properly, e.g.
in PATH I have the three paths to bin, include, finclude and lib
I have a WORHP_LICENSE_FILE set to C:\WORHP\worhp and a WORHP_DISABLE_WONGLE set to True.

Do you have any hints of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

WORHP is unable to find your license file. If it is located in `C:\WORHP\worhp.lic` as you say, you should also set the environment variable `WORHP_LICENSE_FILE` to `C:\WORHP\worhp.lic` (in your post, the file extension `.lic` seems to be missing).

Placing the `worhp.lic` file in the bin subfolder of the WORHP folders as you describe can also allow WORHP to find it, but only if that is the "current working directory" that WORHP is run from. As you say you are using WORHP in CasADi, I assume that that is not the case. You would have to put it in the working directory from which you run CasADi instead.